# java.net.SocketException when trying to read from BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets

Im getting an UncheckedException when im trying to read the lines from BufferedReader

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: 
Connection reset
at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at net.custompayload.LunarRAT.handler.PacketHandler.Packet(PacketHandler.java:31)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:571)
... 9 more
```

Process finished with exit code 130

This is my code, it tries to loop through every module which is like a check for what message it is and it executes the code with the arguments but for some reason when the client sends data to the server it receives nothing

```java
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(), 
StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
reader.ready();
String data = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
    ArrayList<String> args = StringUtils.ConvertStringToArrayListArguments(data);
    for(String module : Module.Modules.keySet()){
        String name = Module.Modules.get(module).getName();
        if(data.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            Module.Modules.get(module).Execute(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue: You should be reading using try-with-resources, so that the socket closes appropriately

Comment: But your socket may be being closed by "the other end"

Comment: The actual cause is 'connection reset', which means the other end sent a RST.

Comment: @accessviolation+ or at least something external did. RST was designed to be end-to-end, but the modern Internet has _lots_ of middleboxes that use it to forcibly break a connection whenever their admins see fit.

Comment: By the way, there is no point in checking if `data` is null.  Collectors.joining will *never* return a null terminal result.